# Jmeter load testing - page load time: 70% of requests complete under 5.5s

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am trying to do performance testing using Jmeter, my client brief says

Entry criteria:
page load time: 70% of requests complete under 5.5s (basic HTML page) 7.0s(page with graphics,images)

Exit Criteria:
page load time: 50% of requests complete under 5.5s (basic HTML page) 7.0s(page with graphics,images)

how come percentage of requests completed for entry criteria is higher than percentage of requests completed for exit criteria.

Please advice,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is standard terminology and advise you to ask you client what he means.
Maybe he means:

- Entry criteria - conditions at initial (low) load
- Exit Criteria - conditions at peak load